# Boundedness of sequence $\{x_n\}$defined as $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n+e^{-x_n}$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers defined as $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n+e^{-x_n}$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$ ; then is $\{x_n\}$ bounded ?

I can easily see it is not a convergent ; but I have no idea about its boundedness.  I can only deduce that $\{x_n\}$ is strictly increasing and that $x_n > 1$ for every $n >1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that bounded increasing sequences are convergent. If you can see (like you say you can) why this sequence is not convergent and why this sequence is increasing, then this sequence cannot be bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, for contradiction, that $x_n$ is bounded by $M$, in other words, $x_n\leq M$.  Then, for all $n$, $e^{-x_n}\geq x^{-M}$.  Therefore, by induction, $M\geq x_n\geq 1+(n-1)e^{-M}$.  However, when $n>(M-1)e^M+1$, the inequality $M\geq 1+(n-1)e^{-M}$ fails.  Therefore, the assumption that $M$ is bounded must be false.  Therefore, the sequence is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

The monotone sequence $$x_{n+1}=x_n+e^{-x_n}$$ is not convergent because otherwise its limit $L$ would have satisfied $$L=L+e^{-L}$$ which is not possible.

Thus the sequence $$x_{n+1}=x_n+e^{-x_n}$$ is not bounded above because an increasing sequence which is bounded above is convergent.